# Can't write dataframe to excel after using groupby function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

Import Excel File as Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

ImportExcelAllDataFlow =pd.read_excel("TmeSpatialFromCenter.xlsx")

aa=ImportExcelAllDataFlow.groupby(['Source', 'TimeFlowContext']).size()
```

I want to write "aa" dataframe to excel. I used the following code to do it. But it doesn't work.

```
TimeSpatialCount.to_excel(TimeSpatialCount.xlsx, sheet_name='sheet1' header=False)
```

Could anyone please tell me the right way to write this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define *doesn't work* also does it work if you change the file type to `.xls` for instance?

Answer (score 0):

> I  want to write "aa" dataframe to excel.

Presumably this means that you want to write:

```
aa.to_excel("TimeSpatialCount.xlsx", sheet_name='sheet1' header=False)
```

*You write the DataFrame `aa` to the file `"TimeSpatialCount.xls"`.*

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I posted one thing wrong here.  You are write. But that is not the problem. I am getting the following error:                                      
  File "C:\Users\mdr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1843, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_excel'                                                                                                        if I import a excel file and write that file, it is working. But after using group by function, it is not working.

Comment: @mizanbuet you can only write a DataFrame to excel, not a Series. You need to convert `aa` to a DataFrame, e.g. `aa.to_frame().to_excel(...)`

Comment: Great! It is working. I thought using groupby function I will get dataframe directly.Thank you very much.